# Run AWS Lambda inside Docker in local

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS and for learning purpose I created a free AWS account. I don't want to install all dependencies, packages and configure them with my test account in my pc until I learn them well. So I planned to create a docker image so I can do configurations later in my pc. But I can't find any good example how to set up docker image for AWS Lambda. Can you please help me to set up docker image?

p.s
I'm using NodeJs

Answer (score 3):

Check out https://github.com/localstack/localstack - A fully functional local AWS cloud stack (Lambda as well).

Comment: can localstack run lambdas that have been implemented as a container? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html

Answer (score 2):

The solution will depend on language you are going to use for lambdas.
Try some tutorials, i.e. the next descibes how to simulate lambda for python:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/

Comment: I'm using Nodejs

Answer (score 2):

Recent **AWS blog** describes how to do it:

- [How do I create a Lambda layer using a simulated Lambda environment with Docker?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/)

Basically you can run already made **docker image** for that:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/

This is the same docker image used by AWS's `SAM` (Serverless Application Model) when you test your lambda **function locally**. Thus this is the closest you can get to the real lambda environment.